# Counting detected objects with tensorflow API

Tags: python, object, tensorflow, detection

I'm using the tensorflow object detection tutorial and everything works great. I get the right number of detected objects. I'm having some issues trying to find a way to count the detected objects and print out the number.

I've looked around the community and found that someone has done it with boxes.shape[0] however, I can't get it to work.

I converted the tutorial to python and removed the calls to matplotlib. I don't need it to output the image with the boxes I just need it to print the number of detected objects.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image




# This is needed to display the images.
#get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")



from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util



# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'test_inference_graph'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model  that is used for the object detection.
    PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('training', 'object- detection.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 1





detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')




label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,   use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)



# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
#TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'IMG_{}.PNG'.format(i)) for i in range(7464, 7483) ]
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'test-latest.jpg') ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
#IMAGE_SIZE = (20, 16)



with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

'''
     # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
         use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=1)
      plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
      plt.imshow(image_np)
 '''
###Below always print 1
#print(boxes.shape[0])
taco = [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
print(len(taco))
```

Comment: The API models usually output fixed number of detections like 100 or 300 for faster r-cnn.  Each detection is accociated with a score (output by all API models). Typically select all detections above a particular threshold (i.e > 0.5)

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Is this threshold adjusted within 'detection_boxes:0'? This will give me the number of objects/boxes in an image?

Comment: You can find source code of the TensorFlow Object Counting API that is an open source framework built on top of TensorFlow that makes it easy to develop object counting systems: https://github.com/ahmetozlu/tensorflow_object_counting_api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
taco = [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
print(len(taco))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `num` variable should contain the number of detected boxes.

Comment: Derek, my output is as follows:      <pre> print(num)     [100.] </pre>     <pre>print(len(num))     1 </pre> I guess maybe this take me back setting a threshold? My understanding is that the threshold is for false positives. I'm not getting false positives, I'm detecting all the objects I want to with on average 95% accuracy. EDIT: sorry for the formatting. Using the mobile app and it's not taking any of my code formatting.

Comment: Could you comment on the model you're using? Is it one of our pretrained models?

Comment: I'm using faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco

Comment: print [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]   -  Gives me: [{'id': 1, 'name': u'taco'}, {'id': 1, 'name': u'taco'}] which is the correct number of tacos in the image. I would much rather just have an interger. I guess I can take the output and convert it somehow.